# How to check if numbers are in correct sequence?

Tags: php, validation, numbers

I have a two dimensional array that contain range of numbers that have to be validated using following rules, range should start from 0 and follow in arithmetic progression.

For example:

```
$array = array();
$array[] = array(0);//VALID
$array[] = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);//VALID
$array[] = array("0","1");//VALID
$array[] = array(0,1,3,4,5,6);//WRONG
$array[] = array(1,2,3,4,5);//WRONG
$array[] = array(0,0,1,2,3,4);//WRONG
```

what is most efficient way to do that in php?

**UPDATE**
I forgot to add that numbers can be represented as string

Comment: Loop through each array and make sure they start from 0 and follow in arithmetic progression?

Comment: so the keys and the vars are all identical, there's a plan

Comment: yes they have to be identical but can be represented as number or string, I'm more concern about performance and memory usage, as each element of array is not limited by length

Comment: not much of an issue with php's lose typing

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compare it to `range($firstelt, $lastelt)`?

```
function isProgression($arr){
    return $arr == range(0, $arr[count($arr)-1]);
}
```

---

Completely arbitrary benchmark:

```
function isProgression($array){
        return ($array == range(0, $array[sizeof($array)-1]));
}

function isProgression2($array){
    $count = count($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i) {
        if($array[$i] != $i){
             return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

for ($x = 0; $x < 1000000; $x++) {
        // Pick one
        isProgression(array(0,1,2,3,4,5));
        isProgression2(array(0,1,2,3,4,5));
}
```

Results:

```
isProgression:   0m2.345s
isProgression2:  0m1.906s
```

Comment: How is instantiating new arrays with `range` for each array entry the "most efficient method"?

Comment: He's not iterating through a loop of any kind, which is just about the only other way I can think of doing it.

Comment: Arbitrary test in `1000000` loops - `0m2.418s` (mine) vs. `0m2.873s` (loop). Make of that what you will.

Comment: Remove the `count()` function from the loop, and declare the size outside of the loop, and re-benchmark. Also, add multiple arrays that will return invalid.

Comment: @Jay nice to know that, and how many items each array contain?

Comment: Never use count() in cycle condition! It's calclated every time. Use another varaiable instead

Comment: @Josh/RiaD - you're right, I copy/pasted an alternative solution without thought. Loop does prove faster overall.

Comment: @mellamokb - "most efficient way" may also refer to a solution that is most easily expressed. With a 0.4s difference over a million loops, this really is a micro-optimisation in normal use

Answer (score 3):

```
array_map(function($inner){
    foreach(array_values($inner) as $key => $value){
        if($key != $value)return "WRONG";
    }
    return "VALID";
},$array)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); ++$i) {
    if($array[$i] != $i){
        //invalid
    }
}
//valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing array by reference may not be optimal for small arrays.

```
 $valid = true;
 foreach ($array as &$inner) {
      $i = -1;
      foreach ($inner as $key => $value) {
           if ((++$i != $key) || ($key != $value)) {
                $valid = false;
                break 2;
           }
      }
 }
```